# Latches Symbol Representation

Tags: latch, symbol

This is logical representation of gated S-R latch :

[image: Logical]
<sub>(source: [ibiblio.org](http://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/Digital/04178.png))</sub>

this is the symbol of it :

[image: Symbol]
<sub>(source: [ibiblio.org](http://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/Digital/04180.png))</sub>

As seen on symbol, in `Q complement` output, there is an inverter. But in logical implementation, there are no inverters since we already got complement of Q. Why there is a inverter in symbol representation? Are both outputs supposed to equal to Q?

Answer (score 4):

The symbolic representation is a black-box. It is only meant to be a representation of the sub circuit (in your case an SR Latch).

Using a not symbol is a classic way of representing that an input or an output has an inverted meaning. In this case it means that !Q has an inverted meaning from Q.

Basically, the symbol should be used in conjunction with the truth table as a black-box. Don't try and draw any conclusions from it of what the underlying logic is.